# hide content using variables with javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

It seems my code doesnt work. Yet i have used this code before and i have it working in another project. Ive been staring myself blind at it. I cant find the problem.

Can i not apply the onClick function like this with the display: function or what..
Or is there a better way of doing this.

It is ment for a button opening my menu.

```js
let menuBtn = document.querySelector(".Btn");
let testing = document.querySelector(".test");
menuBtn.onClick = ()=>{
    testing.classList.add("hide");
}
```

```css
.test {
    display: block;
}
.test.hide {
    display: none;
}
.Btn {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<nav class="test">
    <ul>
        <li>test</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="Btn">test</div>
```

Comment: it is onclick not onClick

Comment: Thank you. Its time to sleep i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small typo on the onclick function. It's onclick not onClick

```js
let menuBtn = document.querySelector(".Btn");
let testing = document.querySelector(".test");
menuBtn.onclick = ()=>{
    testing.classList.add("hide");
}
```

```css
.test {
    display: block;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
.Btn {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<nav class="test">
    <ul>
        <li>test</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="Btn">test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is you asked it to add a class of hide using javascript, but in your css you defined .test.hide

```
/*should be*/
.hide{
    display:none;
}

/*not*/
.test.hide{
    display:none;
}
```